# Math.random() going higher than its supposed to?

Tags: javascript

I know this has probably been answered somewhere else before, but I couldn't find anyone who had the same problem as me. I'm trying to generate a random number with two decimal places after it but sometimes it outputs a higher value then the max.

```
((Math.random() * 4) + 1.8).toFixed(2);
```

For some reason, instead of it generating a number between 4 and 1.8, it sometimes goes higher than four to a value like 5.25 for example. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Everything looks alright to me I dont understand why its not working. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying with `4` will generate a number between `0` and `4` and adding `1.8` will make a random number between `1.8` and `5.8`. To generate a random number between `1.8` and `4` you need to multiply with the difference of range.

```
((Math.random() * (4 - 1.8)) + 1.8).toFixed(2);
//              --^^^^^^^^^^--
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry if I wasted anyone's time or if this was a duplicate question to something else, But I just couldn't figure this out for the life of me. I cant believe it was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` generates numbers between 0 and 1. Imagine it generates `0.9`. Then `(0.9 * 4) + 1.8` is `5.4`. The issue is that you are multiplying by 4 and then adding more above the 4. To fix this, you can use

```
((Math.random() * (4 - 1.8)) + 1.8).toFixed(2)
```

Then, if `Math.random()` produces `0.9`, the result will be `(0.9 * 2.2) + 1.8`, which is `3.78`, less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

`((Math.random() * 4) + 1.8).toFixed(2);`

This part is in parentheses, so will be evaluated first: `(Math.random() * 4)`

That gives you a number between 0 and 4.

Then, you are adding 1.8 to it, which means you will have a result between 1.8, and 5.8, rounded to 2 digits after the decimal point.

I hope this answers your question of why it is not working, and that you can derive your solution now.